# Filter lookup field to show the exsiting folders in the list

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using sharepoint online, and I create a lookup field in the list form and it's display all items in the list as a dropdown list.
Can I filter this dropdown to display only the folders without the other items?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to filter lookup column to only show folders.

As a workaround, in the list A, you could create a column C to record whether items are folders first. Then in the lookup column of list B, filter lookup column based on column C.

References:

[PowerApps filter on Lookup column from SharePoint](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-filter-on-Lookup-column-from-SharePoint/td-p/656292)

[Filter Lookup Dropdown list based on values in another SharePoint list](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Filter-Lookup-Dropdown-list-based-on-values-in-another/td-p/875278)